# MavenError: Failed to execute goal on project: Could not resolve dependencies In Maven Multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, exception, dependencies, multi-module

I am trying to create a maven multi-module project. the project is created successfully but when I am trying to use one module as a dependency of another module, it throws an exception. When I create a module using eclipse, I was selecting packaging as a jar, but when the module is created, the packaging tag was not mention in child pom.xml and I manually insert the packaging tag as a jar. 
following is my parent `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.netsol</groupId>
<artifactId>empirecl</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
-------------------------
<modules>
    <module>empirecl-web</module>
    <module>empirecl-dao</module>
    <module>empirecl-service</module>
    <module>empirecl-api</module>
</modules>
```

Dao Child Module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.netsol</groupId>
    <artifactId>empirecl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>empirecl-dao</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>empirecl-dao</name>
------------------------
```

Service Child Module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.netsol</groupId>
    <artifactId>empirecl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>empirecl-service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>empirecl-service</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netsol</groupId>
        <artifactId>empirecl-dao</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
------------------------------------------
```

The Dao module maven clean and install successfully, but when i trying to use service module, it will generate an following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project empirecl-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.netsol:empirecl-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.netsol:empirecl-dao:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.netsol:empirecl-dao:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.netsol:empirecl:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project empirecl-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.netsol:empirecl-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.netsol:empirecl-dao:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I am trying the find to solution from web, but still the solution is not found. In eclipse when i open the `Dependency Hierarchy` of service module, it shown the DAO module as a folder not jar. below is the screen shot of `Dependency Hierarchy` of service module.

[image]

Comment: The groupId in your parent does not match the groupId referenced?

Comment: @GyroGearless thanks, the parent group id is incorrect in post, other wise in project its same.

Comment: The things you marked in Eclipse output is the workspace resolution in Eclipse. How does your folder strucuture on your hard disk look like?

Comment: the folder structure is `D:\luna_workspace\empire_club\empirecl`.

Comment: it's cause of your root com.netsol:empirecl:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT not installed inside .m2 file. it happen with me when tried to install only sub package needed so I tried to install all the packages and compile worked fine so notice that root package wasn't installed was the difference.

Answer (score 38):

In case anybody comes back to this, I think the problem here was failing to install the parent pom first, which all these submodules depend on, so the [Maven Reactor](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-building-multimodule.html) can't collect the necessary dependencies to build the submodule.

So from the root directory (here `D:\luna_workspace\empire_club\empirecl`) it probably just needs a:

```
mvn clean install
```

(Aside: `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` is not really necessary as [it's the default value](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent)).

Comment: From Eclipse use Run As > Maven build, set goals on clean install.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I forgot it was packaging conflict jar vs pom. I forgot to write

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

In every child pom.xml file

Comment: Where did you write it in the pom.xml file ?

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to insert `<packaging>pom</packaging>` between `artifactId` and `version`

```
<groupId>com.onlinechat</groupId>
<artifactId>chat-online</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>network</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: XML Parser doesn't require elements to be in specific order within the same level. How can this be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the following block of code under `<dependency management><dependencies>` solved the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b06</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This what worked for me -
Go to Java build path --> Order and Export(check JRE system libraries and maven dependencies) in my case these 2 were unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. remove all projects in current workspace
2. import all again
3. maven update project (Alt + F5) -> *Select All* and check *Force Update of Snapshots/Releases*
4. maven build (Ctrl + B) until there is nothing to build

It worked for me after the second try.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your VPN connection, if you are working in home.

Comment: This is no Answer, but a question to the author. Please write things like this as a comment on the question.

Answer (score -2):

Delete or close all other projects, and restart netbeans IDE, and try again.