# Maven build with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, zk

i am trying to configure build of a java project through jenkins.
I have installed the maven plugin and configured the "settings.xml" file.
During the build, I get the following error message:

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project HRWebSuite: Could not resolve dependencies for project sirfin:HRWebSuite:war:3.0: Could not find artifact org.zkoss.exporter:exporter:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT at specified path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HrWebSuiteFutureV3-Test3\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\exporter.jar -> [Help 1]**

The library is present in the specified path and I could not find it as maven dependencies.

Comment: Check this question which has similar error to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673671/mavenerror-failed-to-execute-goal-on-project-could-not-resolve-dependencies-in

Comment: @ShivamPapat I tried to follow the solutions described in the link you posted but I haven't solved.

Comment: I solved it by replacing, in the library path, the backslash character with the slash character.